# Running Puppet Modules

Tags: puppet

This is a terrible question, but I've been beating my head against this for too long.
I've written a custom script to copy a file from the modulepath fileserver to a target directory on the slave nodes. It's currently stored on my master, which I believe is appropriate (You don't want to have to pre-distribute distribution code, right?)

The script is as follows:

```
file { 'sim/':
  path    => '/opt/deploy/puppet_test/',
  ensure  => directory,
  recurse => true,
  source  => "puppet:///modules/sim/sim2/",
  # This source file would be located on the puppet master at
  # /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/sim/files/sim2/ (in Puppet Enterprise)
}
```

The above might be kind of redundant, because I can't tell if the script is working or not, because I literally don't know how to run it. It's entirely possible that I'm blind, but I've got two dozen separate tabs of documentation open, and my frustration is not helping me focus. I tried using `sudo puppet agent --test --verbose` on the master node, and that executed fine, but didn't do anything. The module doesn't show up in classes on the dashboard. I don't know what command I should be running to execute this script. Please send help.

Edit: Nesting this in a class helped move me along, but I still don't have actual copying happening. Looking at the package status for my test script reveals the following:

```
 on 1 node (master)
arch    —
ensure  purged
epoch   —
error   ok
name    testmod
output  —
provider    —
release —
status  missing
version —

 on 1 node (slave)
arch    —
ensure  absent
epoch   —
name    —
output  —
provider    —
release —
version —
```

The module itself doesn't appear on the slave, but I'm not sure if it should or not. It is on the master, but it claims that the value of ensure is "purged." Purge is not enabled in the module.

Answer (score 1):

The resource should be part of a class. For example:

```
# /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/sim/manifests/init.pp

class sim {
    file {
        '/opt/deploy/puppet_test/sim': ...
    }
}
```

Then make sure that your agent manifest includes this class.

```
# site.pp
node 'agent.fqdn.here' {
    include sim
}
```

**Note** that `file { 'subdir': path => '/path/to/dir' }` will not do what you probably think. The `path` parameter will override the *subdir* from the resource title instead of prepending itself. Always use the complete path, either as the title or as the `path` parameter. In the latter case, make the title a description:

```
file { 'resolv-conf': path => '/etc/resolv.dnsmasq' }
```

Comment: I've got it showing up in the classlist on the dashboard now, and I've added it to the group my slave node is a part of. On the dashboard, it says the module is included in the Node details, but it still isn't copying either the module or the files to the slave. I've changed the name to the target path ('/opt/deploy/puppet_test/':) and tried a runonce to prompt a refresh, but it's still in the same state.

Comment: Can you run `puppet agent --test --debug` and put the output onto some paste service?

Comment: The distribution problem has been solved with some basic scripts, so for now I'm abandoning puppet. My instinct is to delete the question, since I'm not sure it was terribly meaningful, but I appreciate the effort in helping me with my issue, and it's possible it might help someone similarly green. Thank you, Felix.